# Why am I unable to use "setImageRecource" to change the drawable used by the ImageView in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm learning how to develop apps for Android, I´m familiar with Java through school courses. Currently, I`m developing a small TicTacToe app for exercise purpose and I´m trying to show a cross instead of a circle but Android Studio cant compile`setImageRecource` command even though in every damn online forum this method is recommended.

I've already tried things like set `setBackgroundRecource` but all these things doesn't fulfill my purpose...

The Java Code:

```
 public void click(View pView){
    if(getActivePlayer()== 1){
        if(s1.getSymbol().equals("cross")){
            pView.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle); //claims cannot Resolve method 'setIMageRecource(int)'
        }
        else{
            pView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cross); //claims cannot Resolve method 'setIMageRecource(int)'
        }
    }
    else if(getActivePlayer()==2){
        if(s2.getSymbol().equals("circle")){
            pView.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle); //claims cannot Resolve method 'setIMageRecource(int)'
        }
        else{
            pView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cross); //claims cannot Resolve method 'setIMageRecource(int)'
        }
    }
    pView.setY(-1000);
    pView.setAlpha(1);
    pView.animate().translationYBy(1000).setDuration(1000);
    if (getActivePlayer() == 1){
        setActivePlayer(2);
        String checker = "aktive player ist gerade" + getActivePlayer();
        Log.i("INfo", checker);
    }
    else{
        setActivePlayer(1);
        String checker = "aktive player ist gerade" + getActivePlayer();
        Log.i("INfo", checker);
    }

}
```

In XML:

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/field4"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:onClick="click"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle" />
```

Comment: Have you considered spelling it correctly?

Comment: Did you find a way to solve the problem? Be sure to keep us updated or accept the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast `View` to `ImageView` like this.

```
((ImageView) pView).setImageResource(R.drawable.cross);
```

Comment: ty perfect solution but actually I still don´t get why I ´m not allowed to cast on the View itselfe....

Comment: @Aaron You can't call setImageResource directly because you provide the `click` method with a `View`. `setImageResource` is a method of the class `ImageView`.  You can change the signature of the method to `public void click(ImageView pView)`. And wherever you call this method you need to provide it with an `ImageView`. Also when yout retrieve the view `R.id.field4` you should do it like this `ImageView pView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.field4);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ImageView.setImageDrawable(Context impact.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.cross));

Here mContext is globally declared as your activity reference.